# $f(x)=\|A^* x \|_2^2 - \| Ax \|_2^2=0$

Tags: normed-spaces

given $f(x)=\|A^* x \|_2^2 - \|  Ax \|_2^2=0$ , $\forall x \in \mathbb{C}$ ,show that $ g(x)= \| (AA^*-A^*A)x \|_2$ $=0, \forall x\in \mathbb{C}$.

It feels like, I have to to differentiate $f(x)$ in some way to get $g(x)$. But since $f'(x)h=<A^*x,A^*h>-<Ax,Ah>$ I think I am stuck. Can some give me a hint how to start here?

Answer (score 2):

Also note that $f(x) = \langle x, (A A^* - A^* A) x \rangle$. Since
$(A A^* - A^* A) = (A A^* - A^* A)^*$, it has a basis of eigenvectors and so
for each eigenvalue, eigenvector pair $\lambda, v$ of $A A^* - A^* A$ we have
$f(v) = \lambda \|v\|^2= 0$.
From this we can conclude that $(A A^* - A^* A) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Rewrite
$$
\frac 12 f'(x)h = \langle AA^*x,h \rangle - \langle A^*A x, h \rangle = 
\langle (AA^* - A^*A)x,h \rangle 
$$

Comment: Thank you. thought this not possible, but actually very clear.